# Spring boot + Docker Compose + Env file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set multiple profiles for spring boot via docker using an env file like so

.env file

```
ENV=docker,test
```

docker-compose

```
  environment:
    - spring.profiles.active=${ENV}
```

this seems to cause spring boot to view `docker,test` as one string if I don't load the env var it works like this

docker-compose

```
  environment:
    - spring.profiles.active=docker,test
```

any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about what problem you're encountering?  An environment variable's value is always a simple string, and the two forms you show should be equivalent; do you have evidence that the application is seeing one differently from the other, or differently from setting a similar environment variable in a non-container setup?

Answer (score 1):

figure out I can do this `env_file: .env`